# How to use div to layout a nav bar, two column div and a bottom div

Tags: html, css

I am tryin to do the following layout:
[image: div layout]

And I have got this code for nav bar:

```html
<nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Book summary</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

then I have two column div like this:

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color:none;">
            <h2>bla bla bla</h2>
            <p>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZdhtRrp.png"  alt="bookshelf">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:none;">
```

How to make a bottom div below the two column div

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Comment: @SMAKSS I end up using the grid system. Thank you

Comment: @SMAKSS I am really sorry, I have pick the other one instead of yours, really sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
            grid-template-areas: 
                "nav nav"
                "div1 div2"
                "div_bot div_bot";
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body > nav{
            grid-area: nav;
            background-color: tan;
        }

        #div1{
            grid-area: div1;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #div2{
            grid-area: div2;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #div_bot{
            grid-area: div_bot;
            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Book summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>

    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>

    <div id="div_bot">Bottom Div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my nav bar is actually horinzontal.... and sorry I am begginer, it look like your divs 1 and 2 they span across the browser...

Comment: If you want ul elements to be horizontal, then you have to add styles to do so (e.g Flex, or make li to display inline). And the divs are taking whole web page because i write `width: 100%;` in body

Comment: Please can you explain the grid bit

Comment: 1fr is a unit like px or %. If you want to have 3 columns with ⅓ screen with each, you can use `1fr 1fr 1fr` and each column will have the same width, you can use `1fr 50px 1fr` then the columns on left and right are the same.

`grid-template-areas` is where you want to have your elements. When I have `”nav nav”` it means that this is ONE element covering 2 columns. And you need to have `grid-area: nav;` in nav style
And everything betweens quote is one row so this mean I have 2 columns and 3 rows

Comment: For more you can go to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ this site is well written to understand how css (end grid) works

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with either a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) system.

1. **Flexbox**. All you have to do is to set your wrapping element display to flex and then make horizontal item alignment with `justify-content` and vertical alignment with `align-items`.

```css
nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

nav>ul>li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.row>.column {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bottom-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Book summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:none;">
    <h2>bla bla bla</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZdhtRrp.png" alt="bookshelf">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:none;">this is another column</div>
</div>

<div class="bottom-row">bottom row</div>
```

2. **Grid**. the grid will be something like this. To achieve this with the grid you should predefine the page layout with `grid-template-areas` and then specify each element to sit on their place.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav" "column1 column2" "bottom-row bottom-row";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  align-self: center;
}

.column1 {
  grid-area: column1;
}

.column2 {
  grid-area: column2;
  align-self: center;
}

.bottom-row {
  grid-area: bottom-row;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Book summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="column1" style="background-color:none;">
  <h2>bla bla bla</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZdhtRrp.png" alt="bookshelf">
  </p>
</div>
<div class="column2" style="background-color:none;">this is another column</div>

<div class="bottom-row">bottom row</div>
```

### More Notes on Grid system

To get started you have to define a container element as a grid with [`display: grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-display) set the column and row sizes with [`grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-columns-rows), and then place its child elements into the grid with [`grid-column` and `grid-row`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row).

- **`display: grid`**. Defines the element as a grid container and establishes a new grid formatting context for its contents.
- **`grid-template-rows` or `grid-template-columns`**. Defines the columns and rows of the grid with a space-separated list of values. The values represent the track size, and the space between them represents the grid line.
- **`grid-column` or `grid-row`**. Shorthand for [`grid-column-start` + `grid-column-end`, and `grid-row-start` + `grid-row-end`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row-start-end), respectively.

Comment: I am a beginner, please can you explain me the "grid" bit

Answer (score 1):

```
i would go with a grid system
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>This grid layout contains six columns and three rows:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to set the following `<div>` opening tag to: `<div style="width=100%;">`.